# I can't understand why my propTypes checks aren't being run on this class

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to get my head around using ES6 class syntax with React, and I've run into an issue I can't understand.

With the class below, for some reason the propTypes checks aren't being run, but I can't figure out why.

```
import { Component } from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"


class Summary extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.displayName = "Summary"
    }


    render() {

        const {ingredients, steps, title} = this.props
        return(
            <div className="Summary">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>
                    <span>{ingredients} Ingredients</span> | <span> {steps} Steps</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
   }

}

Summary.defaultProps =   {
                ingredients: 0,
                steps: 0,
                title: "[untitled recipie]"

        } 

Summary.propTypes = {
            ingredients: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            steps: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            title: function (props, propName) {
                let title = props[propName];
                let valid = null;


                if (typeof title !== "string") return new Error("A title must be a string");
                if (title.length > 20) return new Error("Title's length is over 20 characters");

                return valid;

            }
}

export default Summary
```

If I try to create the element with something like:

```
<Summary title={5} steps="some string" />
```

I get no errors. It just renders the title as "5" and the steps as "some string". It should throw because the propType for steps requires a number and the propType for title requires a string.

#### Things I've tried

- I've tried setting the propTypes as a static property within the class declaration. That didn't work either.
- I've tried setting the propTypes as a property of the instance rather than the class. That definitely didn't work
- I've tried setting the propTypes but no defaultProps. Still no dice.
- I've tried googling for variations on "ES6 class syntax propTypes" and not found anything that can show me what I've done wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the app isn't running in production mode? Since, regardless of multiple issues in your code, `Summary` component should be working.

Comment: I'm just running it in whatever mode webpack does by default. I didn't realise that would have an effect on how the code runs. I assumed it set levels of minification or something.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with your setup. Try moving your `Summary` component to new `create-react-app` project and you'll see the prop types errors. Also, CRA is a good starting point, especially if you're not yet fluent with webpack and etc. env setup. On the Q: share webpack config and any other setup files so we can figure it out.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm currently trying to learn to use the environment without CRA, since I've found that being dropped into an environment that's been set up for me with no explanation makes it very hard for me to trust that my code will run. It's like running ubuntu in production without having any experience of gentoo. Sure your stuff works today, but you have no idea why, and if it breaks, you don't know where to start from to fix anything.

Comment: you signposted to me that the problem was in webpack, and now I know something I didn't yesterday. It was completely unexpected to me that different branches in my javascript files would run or not run based on configuration in my file packager without me explicitly writing that code to check an environment variable. If used I CRA I'd never have known that, and it could have been catastrophic.